# Did this JavaScript break the console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Just doing some JavaScript stuff in google chrome (don't want to try in other browsers for now, in case this is really doing real damage) and I'm not sure why this seemed to break my console.

```
>var x = "http://www.foo.bar/q?name=%%this%%";
<undefined
>x
```

After x (and enter) the console stops working... I restarted chrome and now when I do a simple

```
console.clear();
```

It's giving me

```
Console was cleared
```

And not clearing the console. Now in my scripts console.log's do not register and I'm wondering what is going on. 99% sure it has to do with the double percent signs (%%).

Anyone know what I did wrong or better yet, how to fix the console?

[A bug report for this issue has been filed here.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=446975&can=1&q=double%20percent&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Edit: Feeling pretty dumb, but I had Preserve log checked... That's why the console wasn't clearing.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Chrome 39.

Comment: Really? alright... may wait for more input, but I'll delete if no one can reproduce btw, googlechrome v39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)

Comment: I feel like I'm going crazy -- when you type x, what does it give you? the string?

Comment: Reproduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/g2anoLxn/.  Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m (64-bit)

Comment: The same here with 32-bit. Interesting;

Comment: It's not about %% alone, it's about %% in URL it seems.

Comment: it only breaks it for that tab, by the way. if you open a new tab the console will work again. (for me at least)

Comment: I think I'm on to something!  See: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#string-substitution-and-formatting  You can use "printf" like formatting in the console.  Try `console.log("%s has %d points", "Sam", 100);`.

Comment: `'http://example.com/?n=%%';` - this literal alone breaks it. Leave `http` aside, and it works ok. Wow.

Comment: Can reproduce on Chrome 39 on OS X. Works correctly in Firefox.

Comment: i think it might be a combination of the fact that it's trying to mix the % formatting while trying to format url as a clickable link in the console

Comment: does not reproduce on chrome 38. Seems a chrome 39 issue :<

Comment: @DLeh I think you nailed it. )

Comment: One of the percents is breaking the formatting.  The console continues to work correctly underneath.  If you do `var a = 4; a; alert($_);` then it will correctly report `4`.

Comment: @DLeh: That's gotta be it.  `var x = '%%test%%';` works, but `var x = 'http://%%test%%';` does not.  Maybe we should file a bug report against chrome!

Comment: @user2879041 might need to file a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: This can be reproducer more-minimally by just entering `"http://example.com/%"` in the console. It is not always necessary for two `%`'s.

Comment: i wonder how FF handles the % signs... i tried the OPs example and also console.log("%s has %d points", "Sam", 100);  and it worked both ways

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Also: `'http://%%%'` :-P (for some reason `'http://%'` and `'http://%%'` work!)

Comment: @RocketHazmat My guess would be that Chrome needs 2 characters to follow a `%` to consider it a URL. @Mike That's not exactly the console continuing to work, but the JavaScript completing execution.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: You nailed it!  Chrome needs 3+ characters to display it in the console as a link.  `'http://a'` and `'http://ab'` are **not** displayed as clickable links (even though they can be valid).  `'http://abc'` **is** a clickable link.  So, `'http://a%'` works, but `'http://ab%'` breaks!  That also means `'http://%a'` works, and `'http://%ab'` breaks.

Comment: So, who wants to file a bug report? :-)

Comment: I'll do it a little later tonight, unless someone else would like to

Comment: i propose since OP brought it up 1st they should file the bug report if not then whoever

Comment: I was curious... `console.log('http://ab%s', 'c')` works as "expected" and makes a clickable link (`http://abc`), but `console.log('http://ab%s')` breaks the console.  :-)

Comment: @user2879041: Can you post a link to the bug report?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=446975&can=1&q=double%20percent&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there are actually many different ways of constructing a string that causes this issue, and it is not necessary for there to be two percent signs in most cases.

```
http://example.com/%
http://%%%
http://ab%
http://%ab
http://%zz
```

However, it's not just the presence of a percent sign that breaks the Chrome console, as when we enter the following well-formed URL, the console continues to work properly and produces a clickable link.

```
http://ab%20cd
```

Additionally, the strings `http://%`, and `http://%%` will also print properly, since Chrome will not auto-link a URL-link string unless the `http://` is followed by at least 3 characters.

From here I hypothesized that the issue must be in the process of linking a URL string in the console, likely in the process of decoding a malformed URL. I remembered that the JavaScript function [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) will throw an exception if given a malformed URL, and since Chrome's developer tools are largely written in JavaScript, could this be the issue that is evidently crashing the developer console?

To test this theory, I ran Chrome by the command link, to see if any errors were being logged.

Indeed, the same error you would see if you ran `decodeURI` on a malformed URL (i.e. `decodeURI('http://example.com/%')`) was being printed to the console:

> [4810:1287:0107/164725:ERROR:CONSOLE(683)] "Uncaught URIError: URI malformed", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.js (683)

So, I opened the URL `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.js` in Chrome, and on line 683, I found the following.

```
{var parsedURL=new WebInspector.ParsedURL(decodeURI(url));var origin;var folderPath;var name;if(parsedURL.isValid){origin=parsedURL.scheme+"://"+parsedURL.host;if(parsedURL.port)
```

As we can see, `decodeURI(url)` is being called on the URL without any error checking, thus throwing the exception and crashing the developer console.

A real fix for this issue will come from adding error handling to the Chrome console code, but in the meantime, one way to avoid the issue would be to wrap the string in a complex data type like an array to prevent parsing when logging.

```
var x = "http://example.com/%";
console.log([x]);
```

Thankfully, the broken console issue does not persist once the tab is closed, and will not affect other tabs.

**Update:**

Apparently, the issue can persist across tabs and restarts if Preserve Log is checked. Uncheck this if you are having this issue.

**Update 2:**

As of Chrome 40, this issue is fixed.

Comment: My console issue is persistent across tabs/new windows. It's actually very obnoxious. 

Also, I'm not sure if this necessarily is the correct answer, but I'll mark it for now since you did produce a way of logging that string to the console.


Anyone know how I can reset my console though? Still getting "Console was cleared" and nothing being cleared!

Comment: @user2879041 Hmm, that's odd, it isn't for me. Does it persist across restarts?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara  Persists across restarts. Side note, clear(); used to function correctly, now it's saying undefined-- I have to use console.clear() (like it's IE) to get it to even say console was cleared... Seriously? I guess I'm going to reinstall chrome

Comment: @user2879041: Maybe Chrome isn't being fully closed?  Can't some Chrome Web Apps run in the background?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm using Chrome://restart.

Comment: wow I'm not very bright... I had Preserve log checked... sorry everyone

Comment: @user2879041 Good to know! I've added a not of this to my answer to help future readers.